# SQL FIFO STACK using two tables

Tags: sql, stack, fifo

I have two fields Position and SerialNumber in a table called FIFOStack. What I need is to pull into this table the most recent 100 serial numbers from my table SerialNum. As a new serial number is populated a stored procedure will pull in the new serial number into the FIFOStack table and a different stored procedure will shift out the oldest entry.

I need some explanation on the process and help writing the stored procedures. Thanks

Comment: a "FIFO Stack" is called a "Queue"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of constantly managing another table with stored procedures, you could create a view that functions the same way, and only has to do any work when you query it. Example:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS

SELECT TOP 100 * FROM FIFOStack
ORDER BY Position DESC
```

So, whenever you need this list, you just do:

```
SELECT * FROM MyView
```

And it will always return the latest 100 rows from `FIFOStack`, without any other changes needing to be made.

Comment: The data that would be stored in the table is going to be transferred to a PLC for some error checking. The FIFO data would need to be the last 100. I thought using TOP gave me the highest ranking based on a percentage.

Comment: no, `TOP X` just means "take the first X amount you find"

Comment: Thanks! I would still need the data to be present in that table without manual intervention. In terms of the newest entry at, let's say row 15. If I SELECT TOP 10 * FROM MyTable, I do not see the newest entry at 15, just entries 1-10.

Comment: you need to order it by something. if your serial number is incremental, you can order it by that, otherwise you need a date stamp to order it by. and you'll need to do it in descending order, as noted in my answer. or by your `Position` field.

Comment: OK thanks. At least I have the data viewable. I would need to figure out how to import a new entry into the new table every time a new entry is made into the base table.

Comment: thats just it: you don't have to. whenever you query the view, you're actually just running this query. So instead of "updating" anything, you're actually just querying it for the data you want.

Comment: Yes, but I need to automate the task since the new table needs to stay current. This ensures the FIFO supplied to our PLC has the most current 100 entries. Doing this manually is not optional.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding: the new table is a `view`, which *is always current*, *no matter what*, unless you're not fully explaining something.

Comment: I was able to accomplish this by running the query as a SQL Job

USE Database
Go

Truncate Table [DB].[dbo].[MyTable]


insert into [DB].[dbo].[MyTable]  (serialnumber )
select Distinct top 100 serialnum from MyBaseTable;

Recycles the data every minute on job execution.

Thanks @Dleh. Perhaps I was not very clear about my needs.

Comment: okay, well it seems pretty clear to me that you're doing it the wrong way, but you can't say i didn't warn you.